# Dynamically created button doesn't apply style correctly

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I defined a style in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">240dp</item>
</style>
```

I then apply it to some of the buttons, in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_folder0"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/folder0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_folder1"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/folder1" />
```

Now I want to dynamically create a button and apply the same style, like this (in `MainActivity.kt`):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layout_folders)
    val btn = Button(this, null, R.style.ButtonStyle)
    btn.text = "new button"
    layout.addView(btn)
}
```

However the dynamically created button doesn't have the style. It looks like:

[image]

I have also tried `val btn = Button(ContextWrapper(this, R.style.ButtonStyle))` which leads to a different result but again not the same style as the upper two buttons.

What am I missing? How can I apply the style to a dynamically created button?

Answer (score 1):

Width and height can't be set via themes at runtime.  You need to set them in layout params, and use that when you add it to the parent view.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But even if height cannot be set, why does the `new button` lose all the styles, such as the purple color?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the button using `Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)`

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button#Button(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int)):

> This constructor allows a Button subclass to use its own
> class-specific base style from a **theme attribute** when inflating.

To apply your style to the button, you should use [`Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button#Button(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)) instead.

Comment: So what should I pass in as `defStyleAttr`? I tried to do `Button(this, null, 0, R.style.ButtonStyle)` but then no button is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed that:

```
AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = new AppCompatRadioButton(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyRadioButton), null, 0);

<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_regular</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDefaultFont</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:layerType">software</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_1</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/my_radiobutton_selector</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/padding2</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/padding0</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/padding0</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

So difference is in used constructor, in your case it should look something like that:

```
val button = Button(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ButtonStyle), null, 0)
```

I don't know why, but style applying in code work ONLY when style inherits from some parent default style(possibly it needs to be non material). And when use this 3 params constructor with `ContextThemeWrapper`. Any other combination is useless.